# Delphi OnDeactivate not working on forms from dll file

Tags: delphi, events, dll

I'm trying to call onDeactivate event on form which is part of dll library. It's known issue that OnDeactivate doesn't work when form loses focus to the another application. Unfortunately it seems Delphi treats form from dll library as other application.

I need some workarround for this.

Comment: You have to inform the instance of the VCL that lives in the DLL that it is part of another application. Do so by setting `Application.Handle` to `MainForm.Handle` where `MainForm` is the main form of your app. You'll need to construct a mechanism for your app to communicate the handle of its main form to the DLL. This is yet another reason why packages are to be preferred to DLLs for this sort of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't resolved that. OnDeactivate won't work since main app is treated like another program.

Answer (score -1):

I bit late, but I found a workarround:

Put a timer on the opened form that triggers the event every 1000ms and just check the property Active from the form

Example:

```pascal
if not form.Active then
   myDeactivadEvend();
```